# Mi aplicacion de android studio no corre en mi dispositivo pero si en el emulador?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo una aplicacion en android studio la cual he estado probando en mi celular, funcionaba correctamente pero de un pronto a otro cuando se instala en mi celular se cierra automaticamente, pero en el emulador funciona perfectamente. He probado instalando otros pequenos proyectos y si funcionan pero el que realmente necesito no.

Comment: intenta borrar la cache del dispositivo

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que puedas obtener la ayuda deseada en el sitio, ¿Agrega el mensaje del LogCat?, también puedes obtener reputación para poder realizar este tipo de preguntas en [chat].. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas común que puedes hacer es:
Intentar desinstalar la aplicación de tu dispositivo, borrar todos los datos de la memoria cache.

Si utilizas Android Studio como tu IDE de desarrollo prueba el plugin [ADB Idea](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7380-adb-idea)

Con este plugin encontraras opciones para eliminar los datos y reiniciar la aplicacion, etc, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia por el momento, no sabemos si su emulador tiene un sistema operativo el cual no puede soportar algunas características de la API  en el código, sin el logcat las respuestas al error pueden ser muchas..